# How to check inner arrays that inside of outer array? (Plus => function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, anonymous

**Sorry if these questions are one of basics in JS.**

Issue 1.

I'm trying to make the code detects inner array which is inside of outer array,

and the structure of the array is something like this;

`var array = ['Bob', ['Tim', 'Katy', 'Zoe'], 'Jimmy', 'Jay' . . .]`

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>name goes here</li>
    <li>name goes here</li>
    <li>name goes here</li>
    <li>name goes here</li>
    <li>name goes here</li>
    <li>name goes here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

  const peeps = ['Bob', ['Tim', 'Katy', 'Zoe'], 'Jimmy', 'Jay', 'Louis', 'Yagami Light'];

  $('div ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    for (i = 0; i < peeps.length; i++) {
      if (peeps[i][] in peeps[i] == true) {
        console.log('wow')
      }
    }
  })
```

This is my progress so far but never works the way I expected.

Issue 2.

I stuck to get `this` keyword from arrow function.

```
$('div ul li').on('mouseenter', () => {
  var a = $(this).index();
  console.log(a);
})
```

This code keeps showing -1 for somewhat reason, but after changed the `()` to `function() {}` the code prints 1, 2, 3, 4 as I wanted.

Is there anybody know why `=>` function can't get `this` keyword from that code?

Any tips or infos would be great to solve my issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Second issue is exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions in 1.  Please update your question to remove the second part and ask a second question if needed (though you already have a duplicate for that).

Comment: @freedomn-m I thought it could be spam when if I ask all my questions one by one, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first issue please try using [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if element is an array like below -

```
var peeps = ['Bob', ['Tim', 'Katy', 'Zoe'], 'Jimmy', 'Jay', 'Louis', 'Yagami Light'];

peeps.forEach((d, i) => Array.isArray(d) && console.log('found an array', d))
```

And for second one, it's an issue of "[using this with Arrow functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)". To solve this you can change "arrow function" to es5 function

```
$('div ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var a = $(this).index();
  console.log(a);
})
```

Comment: So the second issue is, there's no way to get `this` keyword from es6 function style?

Comment: Arrow functions treat "this" differently (because of lexical scoping) than normal es5 functions, which in your scenario does not solve the purpose. I would highly recommend reading the link in my answer to get better understanding of where to not use Arrow functions

Note - Arrow functions are not there to replace normal es5 functions, especially when using "this" keyword.

Comment: Thanks for answering and commenting my issue.